# SVG <image> not showing on iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, image, svg

So I'm trying to link an image (rocket.svg) into my svg but when I embed it into my site the svg shows but not the rocket.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:fixed; top:0;      left:0; height:100%; width:100%; user-select: none;">
   <rect style="fill:#33425B;" width="100%" height="100%" id="background"/>

    <!-- Rocket -->
    <image xlink:href="rocket.svg" x="15%" y="45%" width="10vw" height="10vw" id="rocket"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `vw` with your height and width attributes is what is causing the problem, changing it works:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:fixed; top:0;      left:0; height:100%; width:100%; user-select: none;">
  <rect style="fill:#33425B;" width="100%" height="100%" id="background"/>
  <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/NASA_Worm_logo.svg" id="tiger" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I had the same issue because I didn't put any height. I added one and it's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just putting this out there for future folks that have a similar problem. I'm very amateur and was using elementor with wordpress and having problems with my SVGs showing on apple devices. I found the following tool and it fixed my problems!

https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Answer (score 0):

the below code could be useful for temporary solution, we included the svg tag directly inside a div element, providing some attributes for the svg element such as width height and viewBox ('it could be diffrent based on you requirement')
the below code working on iphone 5s running 12.5.5 software version.

note: the div element have some styles it does not require to be inlcuded in your project.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div 
style="height:24px;float: left" 
class="navbar-toggler-icon ">
<svg 
height="24px" 
width="24px"  
viewBox="0 -41 512 512" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M407 0H105C47.102 0 0 47.102 0 105v168.945c0 57.899 47.102 105 105 105h15.582l36.52 46.332a15.001 15.001 0 0 0 23.563 0l36.519-46.332H407c57.898 0 105-47.101 105-105V105C512 47.102 464.898 0 407 0zm0 0" fill="#6787f5"/>
<path d="M407 0H256v378.945h151c57.898 0 105-47.101 105-105V105C512 47.102 464.898 0 407 0zm0 0" fill="#38478a"/><path d="m199.758 401.055 17.426-22.11zM512 123.254H385.879l93.883-93.883C460.875 11.195 435.222 0 407 0h-25.145l-59.613 59.613V0h-132.48v59.613L130.148 0H105C76.777 0 51.125 11.195 32.238 29.371l93.883 93.883H0v132.48h126.121l-90.36 90.356-3.503 3.504c18.887 18.168 44.531 29.351 72.742 29.351h15.582l4.234 5.371 63.336-63.34-1.027 57.97h135.113v-59.407l59.211 59.406H407c28.09 0 53.637-11.086 72.496-29.113l-3.531-3.547-90.25-90.55H512zm0 0" fill="#fff"/><path d="M512 123.254H385.879l93.883-93.883C460.875 11.195 435.222 0 407 0h-25.145l-59.613 59.613V0H256v378.945h66.238V319.54l59.211 59.406H407c28.09 0 53.637-11.086 72.496-29.113l-3.531-3.547-90.25-90.55H512zm0 0" fill="#c7d3ed"/><path d="M292.238 153.254V0h-72.476v153.254H0v72.48h219.762l-2.578 153.211h75.054v-153.21H512v-72.481zm0 0" fill="#ff337a"/><path d="M292.238 153.254V0H256v378.945h36.238v-153.21H512v-72.481zm0 0" fill="#d1005b"/><path d="M199.758 133.25v-21.21L88.945 1.226a104.169 104.169 0 0 0-31.996 10.43L178.547 133.25zm0 0" fill="#ff337a"/><path d="M455.05 11.656a104.169 104.169 0 0 0-31.995-10.43L312.242 112.04v21.211h21.211zm0 0" fill="#d1005b"/><path d="M56.977 367.305a104.307 104.307 0 0 0 32.003 10.422l110.778-110.782v-21.21h-21.211zm0 0" fill="#ff337a"/><path d="M312.242 245.734v21.274L422.641 377.78a104.279 104.279 0 0 0 32.074-10.316l-121.32-121.73zm0 0" fill="#d1005b"/>
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

for server testing environments:
tested obuntu / apache2
tested windows/ xampp